# Function .click doesn't work in ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I try to call a js function from a button. I don't want to use the 'onclick' attribute, so I try to use the .click method. But, the function is never call.

index.cshtml

```
@model List<WebApplication3.Models.Vehicules>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}


<div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" >
</script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/Fonction/FonctionOnLaod.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/Fonction/FunctionVehicule.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-md-12">




                <h4>Bootstrap Snipp for Datatable</h4>
                <div class="table-responsive" id="TableVehicule" onload="scope(); load_events(); date()">

                    <!-- Emplacement du tableau -->

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal -->

    @Html.Partial("Modal/ModalVehicule")
</div>
```

button.cshtml (partialview)

```
@model List<WebApplication3.Models.Vehicules>
<table class="table table-bordred table-striped">

    <thead>
        <tr>

            <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /></th>
            <th>Immatriculation</th>
            <th>Marque</th>
            <th>Model</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
</table>
<table id="CustomerGrid" class="table table-bordred table-striped">
    <tbody>

        @foreach (var vehicule in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkthis" /></td>
                <td>@vehicule.immat</td>
                <td>@vehicule.marque</td>
                <td>@vehicule.modele</td>
                <td>@vehicule.Designation</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="details" href="javascript:;">
                        <label class="button" for="dialog_state">
                            <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit">
                                <!-- the button I want to launch th .click -->
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs IDC-Edit" data-title="Edit"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="IDC-Edit" >
                                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil">

                                    </span>
                                </button>
                            </p>
                        </label>
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs IDC-Delete" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="@(vehicule.id_vehicule )">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">

                            </span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </td>

            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Function.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#IDC-Edit").click(function () {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

When I launch the project, all works but I never see the "test" on the console when I click on the button

Comment: The code should work

Comment: It's doesn't work for me. I never see "test" in the console when I click on the button

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else, is jQuery loaded property? Is that script embedded on the right view? We can only guess.

Comment: Check your browser devtools->console.

Comment: add some detail in the code, but, I check all, and the console send me no error, and no "test"

Comment: Esko, jquery is loaded property, I have many other function who use jquery and work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".IDC-Edit").click(function () {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

you have multiple buttons with same id IDC-Edit, for that you must call them via class id.

Check this link here for clarification of ids and classes.
https://jsfiddle.net/jefm9t4d/3/

Comment: If you look the other attribute of the button, I have id="IDC-Edit".

Comment: I try with the id ans the class, but both doesn't work

Comment: the problem with id was that its only going to work with first button, but in your case i think because of partialview your jquery is not even binding to script.

Comment: for testing add this script in index.cshtml, and tell me the result

Comment: put on the index.cshtml but nothing

Comment: show me your console,
by the way i have added an example for you on  https://jsfiddle.net/jefm9t4d/3/

Comment: My console are white, nothing on it

Comment: instead of console.write use alert to be really sure if you are getting something or not.

Comment: Try all the possibility. I can't change want you want in the function, the error is the .click was never call. I try with alert() but nothing change

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work because, you have use class identifier to catch click event
I think code must be like this, check this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".IDC-Edit").click(function () {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```